# RxDart setup Map on stream

Tags: flutter

I got a setup with a BehaviorSubject. Whenever I load data from an API I call Add to push the data and use it from the stream in a page. Now I want to format some of the data before it is consumed from the stream. As far as I can see Map seems to be the thing to use for a transformation of data, but I'm not sure if it should be set up once or I need to ensure Map is called when data is when data is loaded from an. Currently, I expose a behaviorSubject but if I use map should I then Expose a new stream based on the map?

This is my current setup. From a StreamBuilder in the page I'm using myRides. I can see the applyUnits gets called but its like data is not on the stream anymore

```
    final BehaviorSubject<FeedLoad> ridesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<FeedLoad>();
  Observable<FeedLoad> get myRides => ridesSubject.stream.map((item)=>  item.applyUnits());
```

Comment: That's appears to be a really nice story but I'm not sure if it's about unicorns or war in space ;-) Some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed would be really helpful.

Comment: What do you mean with "expose a new stream based on map". 'map' already does that.